# Fitting figure and centering text in a table as well as adding caption and label

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I'm trying to a make a table with figures in it. But, the figures won't fit in the cells (see example at the end). I'm also trying to make the text in the cells next to the pictures come in the middle of the rows. And of course I'm trying to have all the table lines be visible (see right side of the table).

Is it easier to not use the `multicol` package if I want caption and label for my table? Sense, then I can include it in a table environment and use the `\twoclolumn` command instead.

This is how I have done it so far:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedright, skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, citecolor = red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabular*}{\2\columnwidth}{c|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-5}
    & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Daughter} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$re=0$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$re=0.875$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$k_{3}=0$} 
& \includegraphics[height=2cm]{daughterC1,0.jpg} & $ \frac{Number of division}{3 time points} $

    & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{daughterC2,0.jpg} & $ \frac{Number of division}{3 time points} $ \\ \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$k_{3}=1.6$} & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{daughterC1,6.jpg} & $ \frac{Number of division}{3 time points} $

    & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{daughterC2,16.jpg} & $ \frac{Number of division}{3 time points} $ \\ \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$k_{3}=2.5$} & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{daughterC1,25.jpg} & $ \frac{Number of division}{3 time points} $

    & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{daughterC2,25.jpg} & $ \frac{Number of division}{3 time points} $ \\ \hline

\end{tabular*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like following figure?
[image]

I reproduce one third of your table.  Escaped rows can be easily added. For this image I redesign your table in follows:

- for column type I use `m{>width}`, which provide package `array`. It is added in preamble of MWE
- columns with math are defined as />{$}m{}<{$}. By this I simplify the table code
- nominator and denominator of fraction s are put in text mode
- the width of `m`columns I determine experimentaly

The complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
%    
    \usepackage{amsmath}
%
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[font=small, 
                labelfont=bf, 
                singlelinecheck=false, 
                justification=raggedright, 
                skip=0pt]{caption}
    \usepackage{array}% <-- new
    \usepackage{multicol}
%    \usepackage{showframe}% <-- to see text and page borders
    \begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|>{$}l<{$}|
                             *{2}{m{0.28\textwidth}|>{$}m{0.129\textwidth}<{$}|}}
    \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}    
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Daughter}                                         \\
    \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$re=0$} 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$re=0.875$}                             \\ 
    \hline
k_{3}=0
    &   \smallskip
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
        &   \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time points}}
            &   \smallskip
                \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
                &   \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time points}}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

IN it I omit all packages from your MWE, which are not essential for above figure.